QDoubleValidator валидация чисел с точками и запятыми
Как для класса QDoubleValidator() можно задать разделителем целой и дробной части и точку, и запятую?
Как я понимаю, на разделитель влияет локаль. Однако локалей поддерживающих оба символа я не нашёл. Ещё можно использовать вместо QDoubleValidator(), QRegExpValidator(), но он не поддерживает диапазон значений. Возможно, я упускаю какой-то максимально простой метод?

Унаследуйтесь от QDoubleValidator и в методе validate заменяйте точку и запятую на decimalPoint, полученный из локали.

@needKVAS это работает, спасибо. Но такое решение, мне не очень нравится, мы по сути подменяем вводные данные, это не совсем корректно. Оформите как ответ, приму как корректный)
